# datepicker inside a function is not work

Tags: jquery

```
 $('#toDate').change(function () {
     selectedToDate = $('#toDate').val();
     var year = selectedToDate.substring(6, 10);
     var day = selectedToDate.substring(3, 5);
     var month = selectedToDate.substring(0, 2);
     $('#fromDate').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(year, month-1, day),
        inline: true
    });

});
```

Iam trying to disable past date of a calender. But my code does not work.

Comment: `destroy` the plugin and reinitialize it with the new values. See the plugin documentation for how to destroy.

Comment: can you post your whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use `$( "#fromDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(year, month-1, day) );`

```js
$('#toDate').change(function () {
     selectedToDate = $('#toDate').val();
     var year = selectedToDate.substring(6, 10);
     var day = selectedToDate.substring(3, 5);
     var month = selectedToDate.substring(0, 2);
     
   
   $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(year, month-1, day) );
   /*$('#fromDate').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(2017, 3, 15),
        inline: true
    });*/

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#toDate" ).datepicker();
    $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="toDate"></p>
<p>To:<input type="text" id="fromDate"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 12px; /* just so that it doesn't default to 16px (which is kinda huge) */
}
```

```html
<!-- load jQuery and jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- load jQuery UI CSS theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- the datepicker input -->
<input type='text' id='datepicker' placeholder='Select date' />
```